# VHDL how to assign a input vector value to an integer signal

Tags: vhdl, counter

I'm new to the VHDL, I'm trying to make a counter which receives the value from the input and count to the given value then output a 1;

for example, the input is a 4-bit vector "1011"

I tried to set an integer signal a = input = 1011 = 11 in decimal, then if b = a = 11 output 1, otherwise output 0 and b=b+1

I know that I can do it by a series of if statements, but I'm wondering if there is any better way like assigning the value directly from a input vector to a integer signal? thanks for anyone who can help!

Comment: I think this needs some clarification. So you pass a `value` into a module, it's `count` is initialized to 0, which then increments up to `value` using the reference clock input, then outputs a logic 1? When is it reset?

Comment: You will likely need some form of if statement because this will allow you to define sequential behaviour using registers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, yes, that's what I'm trying to do, I know that I can do it by if statements, like if input="0000" then a = 0, but I'm thinking is there any easier way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but it's the general architecture it sounds like you're after. It's not bad practice to use `if` statements in VHDL; they're necessary to define sequential (not combinatorial) logic; you just need to be judicious in their use.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Counter is port (
     enable:  in std_logic; -- Used to increment the counter. (Active high.)
     value:   in std_logic_vector(0 to 3);
     clk:     in std_logic; -- Used to clock the counter.
     reset:   in std_logic; -- Reset the counter. (Active high.)
     output:  out std_logic -- Generates a logic high once the count has been reached.
);
end Counter;

architecture Behavioral of Counter is

    signal count: unsigned(0 to 3);

begin
    process(clk,reset)
    begin
        -- If reset goes high, reset the count.
        if reset='1' then
            count <= "0000";                -- Reset the counter.
            output <= '0';                  -- Set the output low.
        elsif(clk'event and clk='1') then  -- If not reset, and the rising edge of the input clock...
            if enable='1' then             -- If the counter is enabled...
                if count=unsigned(value) then        -- If the count reached the input value...
                    output <= '1';          -- Set the output high.
                else
                    count <= count + 1;    -- Increment the counter.
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: This is better than what I did first, I made it too complicated when I tried creating a signal as integer, and then I have to use 16 if statements to associate the input value and the integer value, thanks a lot! Also I found that we can actually use integer type as input, but I'm not sure if this works when synthesize, thanks a lot for helping me with this!!!

Comment: Using std_logic_arith and std_logic_unsigned is not recommended, please use std_numeric.

Comment: As Paebbles says, the use of std_logic_arith and std_logic_unsigned is considered bad practice, and has some issues.
You should use the library NUMERIC_STD instead.
I have edited the answer accordingly, but my edit got rejected.

Comment: I reworked the code using this example:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/VHDL_for_FPGA_Design/4-Bit_BCD_Counter_with_Clock_Enable

I didn't pay much attention to the library calls. Why is it considered bad practice? Is it deprecated?

Comment: `std_logic_unsigned` and `std_logic_arith` were never included in the VHDL standards. `numeric_std` is. It also has the benefit of having explicit signed and unsigned types.

Comment: The answer is still not right. You need to get rid of STD_LOGIC_ARITH, and the signal "count" will need type conversion.
As Bill said, std_logic_unsigned and std_logic_arith are NOT standard libraries. They were created by the company Synopsys i believe, and they falsely named them to look like IEEE standard libraries. In addition, they have some issues which can cause unexpected behaviour.
Good practice is: Don't ever use them. Use the IEEE standard libraries instead.

Comment: @AlexT. Check the "Discussion" page on the very wikibook you copied:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Talk:VHDL_for_FPGA_Design/4-Bit_BCD_Counter_with_Clock_Enable
Is explicitly states: "bad example -> it uses synopsys ieee.std_arith and not ieee.numeric_std"